# Count of records is not same in kibana and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am getting data from elastic search to pandas using Search and scan method. My document count is in billions and millions. I noticed a weird thing. When I am matching the numbers in my pandas and kibana for the same time period the numbers are not the same. The greater the duration the more the difference i am getting. Sometimes its more in kibana and sometimes in pandas for the same time period but mostly its greater in pandas. Is this normal? or it is happening because of the volume of data I am parsing?

**Long story short why there is difference in number of records in kibana and pandas?**

Below is the code i am using to get the data from elastic search :-

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import elasticsearch
import elasticsearch.helpers
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from pandasticsearch import DataFrame
from pandasticsearch import Select
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import os


# Define the client which will be our elastic cluster URL
client = Elasticsearch(['localhost.com:9200'])

# Define search method on the client by using the Search function.
search = Search(using=client)  # make sure that the Search function start with Capital S (Search(using=client)) as this is a function.

# Get all the results from the search method and store it in result to know how many hits we are getting.
results = search.execute()

# To know about the total number of hits we are getting run the below chunk.
results.hits.total  # (I got 3.9 billion hits as a result)


# Again I am defining a method s on which we will perform the query. you have to run this method everytime before running the query.
s = Search(using=client)

# add any filters/queries....

# The below line you can use if you want to dump all the data and in this case we have 2.3 billion observation.
#s = s.query({"match_all": {}})

# In the below code you can add filters,queries or time constraints.
s = s.query({"constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                 "bool" : {
                    "must" : [{
              "range": {"@timestamp" : {
                "gte": "2018-09-20T16:00:00.000Z", # gte - greater than
                "lte": "2018-09-20T17:00:00.000Z"  # lte - less than

            }}
          }],
                   "filter": [
                        {"term"  :{"type" :"abc"}}, 
                        {"term"  :{"ua" :"xyz"}},  
                        {"term"  :{"domain":"ghj"}},]        

                 }}}})

# After getting all the result in the variable s, we are applying scan method on it and converting it into a data frame.
results_df = pd.DataFrame((d.to_dict() for d in s.scan()))
```

Comment: You're not defining any specific index in your search?

Comment: my index are daily dates so its working like that. Have you faced this kind of issue. ever

Comment: there might be a timezone issue as Kibana shows dates in the browser timezone. Have you checked the query that goes out to ES using the Inspector/Spy panel ?

Comment: I checked the timezone...They are same...difference is not much its kind of 1% only but i am curious why i am getting more numbers in pandas.   I am not sure what is inspector/spy panel is.  But my issue is with kibana. I am not getting exact figure on kibana dashboard.  M i making sense?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and i just got one answer that, The problem with elasticsearch is that is updates the index only every so often (by default every second) when a refresh happens so the number might not be 100% accurate at any given moment.

You can refer the below link where i have posted the issue but couldn't get much help:-

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/1019#issuecomment-423372421